# SubscriptionInfo.getMnc() drops leading zeros, cannot link MCC+MNC to SIM operator

Tags: android

I'm updating some code to use the [Multi SIM support](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.1.html#multisim) that was added to Android in 5.1. We examine the SIM operator (or the MCC+MNC combo) a lot in our app, so the code I'm writing involves migrating from reliance on TelephonyManager.getSimOperator() to getting SubscriptionInfos from the SubscriptionManager, each of which gives access to the MCC and MNC for a SIM.

```
//old way – can only access one SIM
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String simOperator = telephonyManager.getSimOperator();

//new way - gives access to all SIMs
SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager = (SubscriptionManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);
List<SubscriptionInfo> subInfoList = subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
for(SubscriptionInfo info : subInfoList) {
    int mcc = info.getMcc();
    int mnc = info.getMnc();

    //do some stuff...
}
```

I'm finding that because it's returning ints for MCC and MNC, you lose leading zeros that are in some of the MNCs. To see some examples, check out the table [here](http://mcc-mnc.com/). When you concat MCC+MNC you get the SIM operator, so it is important to keep the zeros that are often present. For example, NEXTEL in Mexico has a SIM operator value of "334090," but because the SubscriptionInfo returns ints for MCC and MNC, you get the values 334 and 90, respectively.

Given this issue, how can you reliably link a SubscriptionInfo's MCC+MNC pair to a particular SIM operator in a list of known SIM operators? Is this an oversight in the design of this API? Is there any other way to get the SIM operator for every SIM card that's in the multi-SIM phone?

Answer (score 0):

MCC are always 3 digits, the rest is MNC, which as you correctly said, may have 2 or 3 digits.

If you parse the int to String, you can just get sub string of it and process the info as required.

Also it's a hidden method, but you can access it by reflection, to get the info you want in String format, this exists at least from [Android 6](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/telephony/java/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.java#L1757) and [Android 7](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/nougat-release/telephony/java/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.java#L1869)

```
public String getSimOperator(int subId)
```

But I think SubscriptionManager way is safer since it's open API and for the moment you don't need to bother with Android versions handling it differently.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to read IMSI from the SIM card. If you are reading the MNC+MNC directly and your user is on roaming or connected to another network then the values returned won't be reliable.

E.g. If your user is NEXTEL customer but is travelling or due to network connection issues connects to another network, lets say Telcel, then the value returned from MCC+MNC will be from Telcel.

In order to reliably match the operator of current SIM to predefined list, read IMSI value from SIM card using [getSubscriptionId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSubscriberId()) from Telephony manager.

[IMSI starts with MCC+MNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_mobile_subscriber_identity) of the operator. You can easily check if MCC+MNC matches as follows

```
final String mccMncToCompare = "334090"; //You can also use Integer instead of string. You just have to perform type conversion
final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
final String imsi= tm.getSubscriberId();
final boolean mccMncMatched = imsi.startsWith(mccMncToCompare);
```